# can anyone please tell me whats the error with usage of bean in the jsp

Tags: jsp, javabeans

An error occurred at line: 24 in the jsp file: /Home.jsp
JavaBeanDemo cannot be resolved to a type

```
21: <jsp:useBean id="jb" scope="session" type="JavaBeanDemo" />
22: 
23: <strong>Hello, </strong>
24: <jsp:getProperty property="fname" name="jb"/>
25: <br>
```

Comment: Please share the code that produced the error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like you have not specified the fully-qualified name of bean.  You need to include the package name, not just the class name, e.g. com.foo.bar.JavaBeanDemo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use <jsp:useBean>: "Bean cannot be resolved to a type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329451/cant-use-jspusebean-bean-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad, i didnt set values to the attributes which i try to get!
Sorry guys!

There is nothing wrong in the code!